# Sorting DataFrame by datetime64[ns]-dtype column values not working as expected. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, python-datetime

I have a chronological-disordered list stored in a excel sheet called 'Compilado' that I want to reorder correctly to prepare for data analysis.

I parsed it to a Pandas Dataframe running:

`df = pandas.read_excel(r'C:\Users\KMBGSI\Downloads\Historico de Alertas.xlsx',sheet_name='Compilado', header=None, names= header_list, index_col=None, parse_dates=[0])`

Dataframe preview:

[df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut2GR.png)

df.info() returns:

[return from df.info()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VteYF.png)

so dtypes are okay.

Data from column 'Data' seems to have been parsed right and is shown in the format dd/mm/YYYY.

However, when I run the code below data from column 'Data' seems to have its format changed:

```
df.sort_values(by=['Data'], inplace=True)
df.head()
```

[dataframe preview after sorting by 'Data' column values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiZqc.png)

I know '2021-01-12' is actually '2021-12-01' wrongly formatted, because my dataset begins in 01/09/2021 (2021-09-01).

Why does it happen?
How can I reorder this dataset keeping datetime64[ns] values correclty formatted?

Thanks! Kind regards,

**Full code for reference:**

```
import os, sys, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

header_list = ['Data', 'Hora', 'Status']

df = pandas.read_excel(r'C:\Users\KMBGSI\Downloads\Historico de Alertas.xlsx',sheet_name='Compilado', header=None, names= header_list, index_col=None, parse_dates=[0])

"comment after checking dataframe is okay before proceeding"
#df.info()
#df.head()
#df.tail()

df.sort_values(by=['Data'], inplace=True)

df.head()
```

Comment: I've also tried setting 'Data' column as index through `df.set_index("Data")`, so that I could use sortt by index method, but it also 'changes' the way data is exhibited when I run`df.head()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right  `df.sort_values()` converts the format from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy-dd-mm`

You can change the format after `df.sort_values` by this command:

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

However, the datatype of the column will change to `object`

To convert back to `datetime64[ns]`

```
df['Data']=pd.to_datetime(df['Data'])
```

You can check the documentation of `df.sort_values()` here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Thanks!
I had a look upon some tutorials on internet and found this:
https://statisticsglobe.com/sort-pandas-dataframe-date-python

I've repeated the steps and it wen right.

I would like to know why. What am I missing?

Comment: @rdgui1991 I am not sure exactly what is happening under the hood. I showed a way to convert back to the desired format using `df['Data'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')`. You can change to any format using this formula.